# How to write the script that takes values from a checkbox and inserts it as different columns in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a form for creating new events in Oracle Apex. With that form I am able to create new events just fine. But at the bottom of that form is a checkbox where the user will specify the clubs that are involved in organizing the event.

[image]

The list of values for the checkbox which you can see at the bottom of the image above is set to a sql query which selects 'club_name' and 'club_id' from 'club' table.

[image]

Now what i want to do is after the events gets successfully created,  the club_id of the checked clubs with the id of the newly created event needs to be inserted into the 'club_event' junction table which relates each event with their organizing club. So I need to create a page process that inserts the records into the junction table. I tried writing a script in the "Server-side Condition" section of the page designer that appears after I select "Processing".

[image]

```
DECLARE
    type idarray IS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(10);
    ids idarray;
BEGIN
    ids := apex_string.split(:P72_CLUBS, ':');
    FOR id IN ids LOOP
        INSERT INTO club_event
        VALUES(id, P72_EVENT_ID);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Is this the way to use the page process to do what I want to do? What is wrong with my script and how may I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "server side condition" is an attribute on an apex component that determines if the component needs to be executed. In your case you already have a "When button pressed" condition so you can leave the "Type" empty. 
The code that needs to be executed in the page process should go in the "Source" as shown below.

[image]

Your code doesn't execute - I suggest you try that in the sql workshop to figure out what is wrong (multiple errors, I'm not going into detail here). I usually use something like this:

```
DECLARE
    l_ids apex_t_varchar2;
BEGIN
    l_ids := apex_string.split(:P72_CLUBS, ':');
    FOR i IN 1 .. l_ids.COUNT LOOP
      INSERT INTO club_event 
        VALUES(l_ids(i), :P72_EVENT_ID);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: It implemented your script. I am getting "Error processing process". I ran the script in "SQL commands" with hard coded ids and it workd. Any ideas? I also have a follow up questions what if i there is no :P72_EVENT_ID and i want the event id to be of the event just created. How may I do so? If you could tell me what apex_t_varchar2 data type is it would be great. Big thanks for your help?

Comment: Hello Saman, debug your application to find out why the process is erroring out https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmdb/utilizing-debug-mode.html#GUID-65F66F2B-ADCB-41B2-8EEE-3B7D7603F50C. Lots of assumptions in your followup question. Make sure you "Automatic Row Processing" process runs *before* this process. Look for the attribute "Return Primary Key(s) after Insert", that will populate P72_EVENT_ID with the newly created event id. If that doesn't solve it pls post a new question.

Comment: It sounds as if you're very new to apex, it will help you to go through some documentation, youtube videos and blogs. Create lots of test apps on the sample data sets provided by oracle. Asking questions on stackoverflow is a very slow learning process.

Comment: I am on a tight deadline so decided to straightly jump into building my project and learn as I go. Setting "Automatic Row Processing" to run before the process I created worked and new P72_EVENT_ID is now successfully populated? I will look into the documentation. Thank you.